# NodeJs middleware hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

I am learning Node.js and I tried splitting the middleware logic from the main file.

I have the following structure:

index.js:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

const login = require("./middleware/login");

app.use("/login", login);

app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('1');
})

var portnumber = 3002;

app.listen(portnumber, () =>
  console.log("Express server is running on localhost:" + portnumber)
);




../middleware/login.js:

const { default: axios } = require("axios");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const login = () => {
  var URI =
    "left empty for security reasons";

  mongoose.connect(URI, { useNewUrlParser: true }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    handleError(error);
  });

 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     res.send('1');
     next();
 });
  

};

module.exports = login;
```

I try understanding how the whole system works, I do know that the code hangs because it doesn't know what to do after finishing with the login component.

Answer (score 1):

`app.use()` will try to pass `req, res, next` as arguments to your login() method, which currently isn't possible. So you want to remove the app.use part of your login() method and move the parameters to login() as such:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

const login = require("./middleware/login");

app.use("/login", login);

app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('1');
})

var portnumber = 3002;

app.listen(portnumber, () =>
  console.log("Express server is running on localhost:" + portnumber)
);


../middleware/login.js:

const { default: axios } = require("axios");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const login = (req, res, next) => {
  var URI =
    "left empty for security reasons";

  mongoose.connect(URI, { useNewUrlParser: true }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    handleError(error);
  });

  res.send('1');
};

module.exports = login;
```

Comment: I also rather doubt the OP wants to call `mongoose.connect()` on every login request.  I would hope they are caching that connection, but perhaps we're only seeing part of their code.

Comment: Where you advice me to keep the database connection then? Have it in a separate file which would be called with app.use() in the index method or living directly on the index file?